# Ways of keeping DLLs up to date

Tags: dll, filesystems, dependencies

I've recently joined a company which has had a number of developers of varying quality work for them over the years.

The projects which have been created rely on outputs from other projects.
However instead of creating dependencies in the normal manner and maintaining the code, DLLs have been copied from one place to another and referenced from there.

Is there an easy way to update all of my DLLs under a parent folder to the most recent version of that (by timestamp) accross the whole range of folders ?

So the process in summary:

1. Compile all of the projects and
   solutions all in a root folder.
2. Find and update all other copies of
   the output files.
3. Recompile everything and find out
   what breaks.
4. Update source code and update
   references.

The problem step is 2.

(I'm quite aware that this may break stuff)

I'm using Visual Studio 2005 and C# to create the DLLs, however I want to update the files rather than the code preferably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easier approach would be to create a solution that contains all the projects you need, modify the references between them to use project references, change the projects so their output folders all point to the same directory, and then setup the project references so that "Copy Local" is set to false.

Then all you need to do is build the solution (either in VS or on the command line via msbuild).

The build result would be a single folder that has all the files you need in it, and every project would always have up to date references.

Comment: Its simple, easy, unobtrusive and maintainable.

I think we have a winner.

Answer (score 8):

The Microsoft best practice advice is to reference projects rather than DLLs wherever possible.

> **Project-to-Project References and File References**
>
> File references are direct references
>   to assemblies; you create them using
>   the Browse tab of the Add Reference
>   dialog box. Project-to-project
>   references are references to projects
>   containing assemblies; you create them
>   using the Project tab of the Add
>   Reference dialog box.
>
> The advantage of a project-to-project
>   reference is that it creates a
>   dependency between the projects in the
>   build system, so the dependent project
>   will be built if it has changed since
>   the last time the referencing project
>   was built. A file reference does not
>   create a build dependency, so it is
>   possible to build the referencing
>   project without building the dependent
>   project, and the reference can become
>   obsolete (that is, the project can
>   reference a previously built version
>   of the project). This can result in
>   several versions of a single DLL being
>   required in the bin directory, which
>   is not possible. When this conflict
>   occurs, you will see a message such as
>   Warning: the dependency 'file' in
>   project 'project' cannot be copied to
>   the run directory because it would
>   overwrite the reference 'file.'.
>
> You should avoid adding file
>   references to outputs of another
>   project within the same solution,
>   because doing so may cause compilation
>   errors. Instead, use the Projects tab
>   of the Add Reference dialog box to
>   create project-to-project references
>   within the same solution. This makes
>   team development easier by allowing
>   for better management of the class
>   libraries you create in your projects.
>   For more information, see
>   Troubleshooting Broken References and
>   How to: Create and Remove Project
>   Dependencies.

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez524kew(VS.80).aspx).

Comment: While I realise that it is best practice to refer to the projects. How can I get from the situation I'm in to a best practice scenario ?

Comment: like that's really going to make me want to spend my time helping you!

Comment: "How can I get from the situation I'm in to a best practice scenario" - by removing DLL references from your projects and reference the actual projects.

Comment: Perhaps you would like to update your question to explain why you can't reference projects??

Comment: I have a similar issue Micth.  I'd love to reference projects instead of DLLs.  But my project is in VS2008 and the donor projects are VS2003.  When I try to reference the project VS wants to convert them to 2008.  

The donor projects are still being actively developed in VS2003 so conversion to 2008 is not an option.  I considered creating a duplicate VS2008 project for each donor DLL. But this would result in two versions of these DLLs existing, one generated by VS2003 and one by VS2008.  I'm sure this would eventually add to the confusion.

Comment: @Paul Mitchell: so your company is developing using two different versions of VS, presumably since the VS2003 use 1.1 of the framework? If that's the case I would look at ways to upgrade to 2.0, and then you can target 2.0 of the .NET framework using VS2008. That way, everyone can upgrade to VS2008.

Comment: Yes of course we're looking at upgrading to VS2008.  But with dozens of developers and more than a million lines of code it's not a small project. And in the meantime issues like this cause a lot of pain.  In fact I fully expect that by the time we're fully migrated off of VS2003 on to VS2008, other devlopers will be using VS2015...

Comment: Thanks mitch I appreciate your input, but I'm aware that the ideal is to use project references however I'm far from the ideal.

I'm trying to figure out the best way of getting from A to B.

I've added a summary to clarify things.

Comment: That's a really good point: Projects in solutions. But many times you use projects outside your solution. I guess there you can find the problem

Answer (score 5):

There are times when project-to-project references don't work. For example build time of projects, or wanting multiple projects to depend on a particular build of a reference, or if testing of the referenced project is complete and you don't want to test things again.

If you have a continuous integration system, and version control, then an alternative is to check in built dlls into version control as part of the CI build. Then reference the dlls (e.g. an external in svn) to the dependent project, this should mean that all your dlls stay up to date.

Comment: We do that and reduces the time to build and the code loaded on the IDE.

Answer (score 2):

Could you add a post-build step to the included-but-not-really-included projects to dump the DLLs to a prearranged location? From there, you could add a pre-build step in the dependant projects to grab new DLLs from said location. Definitely not best practice, but it should get the job done.

Comment: This is kind of how its got to this situation so far we have lots of people copying DLL's from not quite so shared locations.

TBH it would work and its the best suggestion so far.